# Only want to allow certain certain characters in a string

Tags: php, character, strpos

How can I only allow the characters W, L, and D in a string? I have written this

```
if ((strpos($input, 'w') === false) 
 && (strpos($input, 'd') === false) 
 && (strpos($input, 'l') === false)) { 

 $answer = "FALSE";

} else {

 $answer = "TRUE";

}
```

but this only works if **all** the characters are W, L, D or **none** of the characters are W, L or D. I cant work out how to get it to spot when just some of the characters are incorrect.

eg

wwwlld = TRUE (correct)
12aab6 = FALSE (correct)
www44d = TRUE (incorrect, this needs to be FALSE as it contains '44')

Any help much appreciated.

P

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of requiring [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which are the [preg_match function in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

You probably want to use something like the following

```
$pattern = '/^[wdl]*$/';
```

This would only match a string where between the start and the end of the string, 0 or more characters in the set w, d or l.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for this using the pattern `^[wdl]+$`:

```
$values = array('wwwlld', '12aab6', 'www44d');

foreach($values as $value)
{
  echo $value;
  if (preg_match('/^[wdl]+$/', $value))
    echo " = TRUE\n";
  else
    echo " = FALSE\n";
}
```

Output of the above:

```
wwwlld = TRUE
12aab6 = FALSE
www44d = FALSE
```

Online demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a63e9f692fcdd44daad28821cca4a59dddffcc25).

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = "wwwlld";
preg_match('/^[wdl]+$/', $subject, $matches);
echo ($matches) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

**Output:**

```
//wwwlld = TRUE
//12aab6 = FALSE
//www44d = FALSE
```